# How can I manually create an identity and authenticate them in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using the default MVC 5 project and I to protect the following method, so that only the user logged in as "foobar" may access it.  This special user will exist outside of the normal database (and be defined in the web.config, but for now it is hard-wired)

```
    [Authorize(Users = "foobar")]
    public ActionResult Install()
    {
        //setup database;
        return View();
    }
```

And I'm checking the login method for foobar, and if detected, I want to login them in and then redirect them to the Install action.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
         if (model.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == "foobar" && model.Password == "pass")
                {
                  //create an Idenity named foobar and log them in
                  return RedirectToAction("Install");
```

Comment: Just curious why would you create a special user with a hardcoded password outside of the normal database? There are a number of safeguards built into the default user storage (password hashing) that you won't have with this one-off account.

Answer (score -1):

```
        string username = model.username;
        string password = model.password;

        // This is where you do your super user check against the config file
        bool userValid = true; // compare id and password against config.
        // this is a bad idea, back door user is a security hole that can be exploited

        if (userValid)
        {
            //this will set the identity and the cookie for your user
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
        }
```